# Sencha touch NavigationView

Tags: navigation, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to figure out the use cases when one should use NavigationView.
Could someone give me some examples?

Comment: Please do some research. A lot of available sencha resources for you.

Comment: I'm not searching for code example but for real life use case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigation view is what most people used for straight forward cases.
Navigation view automatically controls the history and back buttons for the navigation and cleans up when a panel is popped out of view.

Some applications have a twisted navigation, where the back button might not always take the person to the immediate back panel. Also in some cases, we might want to show a single panel out of a collection based on a condition. This can be easily done using a panel with layout as 'card'. If you use the navigation view for these situations, it might be a bit overwork to recreate the same views every time.

Comment: What puzzle me is there are only push and pop methods you can use (as I have seen answered on Sencha forum) so NavigationView can't be used in cases where you want to navigate freely inside the pushed list of items?

Comment: For that, u are going to need to use a panel with layout as 'card'.

Comment: Ok, I understand now the restrited area of use of the VavigationView. Many thanks